# Read all pages from PDF c#

Tags: c#, pdfium

I want to read all pages of my PDF and save them as a images, so far what I am doing is only getting me the page defined `0 = 1` first etc .. Is there a chance that I can define a range ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   try
   {
      string path = @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\pdfToWord\";
      foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.pdf")) { 
      using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(file))
      {
         int i = 1;
         var image = document.Render(0,300,300, true);
         image.Save(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\pdfToWord\output.png", ImageFormat.Png);
          }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // handle exception here;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your document-object gives you the pagecount,

you could replace

```
int i = 1;
var image = document.Render(0,300,300, true);
image.Save(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\pdfToWord\output.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

by

```
for(int index = 0; index < document.PageCount; index++)
{
     var image = document.Render(index,300,300, true);
     image.Save(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\pdfToWord\output"+index.ToString("000")+".png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```